# Create IPython notebooks with some cells already populated

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I create a new IPython notebook it opens a blank notebook. I would like instead that all my notebooks open with a few cells already populated with stuff that I always use. For example, the first cell would have some magic commands

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
%matplotlib inline
```

The second cell might contain some standard imports

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from tabulate import tabulate
```

Is it possible to tell IPython somewhere how to template new files so that this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a configuration file for ipython as described [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html). For example run:

```
ipython profile create
```

to create a default ipython profile (probably with the name `${HOME}/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` directory) (or you could just create this file yourself). You could then edit this to include e.g.:

```
c = get_config()

c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
    '%load_ext autoreload',
    '%autoreloud 2',
    '%matplotlib inline',
    'import numpy as np',
    'import matplotlib as mpl',
    'from matplotlib import pyplot as plt',
    'from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection',
    'from netCDF4 import Dataset',
    'from tabulate import tabulate'
]
```

However, this just runs commands in the background before your notebook ipython session starts and doesn't actually populate the first cell.